# How to identify how many instances of Oracle are installed on Linux environment

Tags: linux, oracle, redhat

Last day, I was at one training for Oracle installation and service start & shutdown. There I came to know about some Linux commands to start and shutdown an Oracle instance on a Linux machine.

**To identify the instance running** : The command below will return all Oracle instances which are currently running on that machine.

```
ps -ef | grep pmon
```

This command returns following results:

```
oracle    823     1  0 Dec03 ?        00:00:17 ora_pmon_instance1
oracle  19632     1  0 Nov17 ?        00:06:35 ora_pmon_instance2
oracle  24199     1  0 Nov20 ?        00:05:23 ora_pmon_instance3
```

Where `instance1`, `instance2` and `instance3` are 3 installations of Oracle on Linux, which are currently running.

**My query:** So, `ps -ef` will only show processes currently running. Suppose, `instance3` is down and you need to start that instance. But, you don't know how many Oracle instances there are on the machine.

How would you get to know that this instance is down?

In Windows, there is a way called services, where you could came to know that these installations are done on Windows for Oracle.

Comment: There is no guaranteed method.  That's something that should be documented.  You can look for indicators like entries in /etc/oratab but that is no guarantee if someone has really fouled up a server.  Just as in Windows, it is possible to not have a service though that wouldn't generally be sensible.

Comment: Yes, i have tried the way to grep information from file system like /etc/oratab

Comment: And that didn't work for some reason?  As I said, if you're assuming that someone in the past did installs in a non-standard method, didn't document anything, and the instance isn't running any longer, then they've done an excellent job of hiding it.  You can search for things that look like parameter files and spfiles or data files but that likely requires human intervention to determine if they are "real".  That's true regardless of OS.

Comment: @JustinCave : Yes, i have discussed it with dba at my side. He told the same thing, that, if you are installing anything, then you should document  it for future reference. Way is only to analyze the folder structure and find out installations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no fool-proof way, but here's a list of ideas for you:

**/etc/oratab:**

Little script to give you a list of SIDs in the `oratab`:

```
cat /etc/oratab | grep -v '^#\|^\s*$' | cut -d: -f 1
```

**$ORACLE_HOME/dbs**

You can adapt the above script to look in all `$ORACLE_HOME`s listed in the `oratab`, and search for initSID.ora and spfiles for any instances:

```
for ORACLEHOME in `cat oratab | grep -v '^#\|^\s*$' | cut -d: -f 2 |uniq`
do 
  ls -1 $ORACLEHOME/init*.ora | sed -n 's/init\(.*\).ora/\1/p'
  ls -1 $ORACLEHOME/spfile*.ora | sed -n 's/spfile\(.*\).ora/\1/p'
done
```

**tnsnames.ora / listener.ora**

Another option is to look in each `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` and analyse the `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora` files to see which instances have been configured.

**Already Running Instances**

You've already covered this with your `pmon` search. You can also use `lsnrctl status` to see which instances the listener is currently servicing requests for.

Comment: Thanks @Phil , So far i found this answer is more relevant. thanks for such nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

IF Oracle restart is in place, as is often the case when RAC and/or ASM is in use, you can use:

```
crsctl stat res -t -w "TYPE = ora.database.type"|awk '/^ora./ {l=$0;} !/^ora./ { if ( l > "" ) l=l " " $0; print l;l="";}'|grep  ${HOSTNAME%%.*}
```

to list the databases that are defined on the current host. This comes very close to the Windows services. You could pipe this into the next lines to filter out the database name and request that status of the database, where the instances are listed:

```
awk -F"." '{print $2}' |while read db
do
  srvctl status database -d $db
done| grep  ${HOSTNAME%%.*}
```

In case of RAC this again introduces instances running on other nodes so again, filter using the current HOSTNAME

Comment: We've both gone all SuperUser on the OP with our shell antics :P

Comment: antics .... like know how you can help yourselves .... ? Creativity.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I look at the `/etc/oratab` entry. But that is again not fool proof as it could be edited by someone having the privilege to edit the file.

For example,

```
-sh-4.1$ ls -lrt /etc/oratab
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oinstall 729 Nov  2 12:30 /etc/oratab
-sh-4.1$ cat /etc/oratab
#



# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by the Database Configuration Assistant when creating
# a database.

# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#
orcl:/scratch/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1:N
```

Since I have only one database instance named **orcl**, there is only single entry in the file. If you have multiple entries, then **DBCA** updates and adds each new entry in the file created by **root.sh**.